# Is it possible to pass Calendar new date in the bean without listener?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, calendar, primefaces

I am trying to pass new date from PrimeFaces p:calendar (placed in p:dataTable column) to the backing bean:

```
<p:column >
    <p:calendar value="#{bean.date}">`
        <p:ajax />
    </p:calendar>
</p:column>
```

It does not update bean.date. Variants with

```
<p:ajax update="@this" event="change"/>
<p:ajax update="@this" event="select"/>
```

do not update bean.date too. The only way I have found is using of listener. However, I suppose, there should be a way without listener implementation like for simple facelets:

```
<p:column>
  <h:inputText value="#{bean.note}" >
      <f:ajax/>
  </h:inputText>
</p:column>
```

that works fine for me. Does anybody know how to get it working!?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <p:calendar value="#{Bean.value}">
   <p:ajax update="display" event="dateSelect" listener="#{Bean.handleDateSelect}"/>
 </p:calendar>
```

This should be helpful...but without listener means i dont think soo..you cant...

Comment: This works but when user try to enter the value to the text field backing bean is not updated.

Answer (score -1):

p:calendar it's a bit tricky for ajax; onSelectUpdate & selectListener are the key;

```
<p:column>
  <h:inputText id="itDate" value="#{bean.note}" >
      <f:ajax/>
  </h:inputText>
</p:column>
```

and you must implement the handleDateSelect method in the Bean;

```
public void handleDateSelect(DateSelectEvent event) {
    Date date = event.getDate();
    setDate(date);
    }
```